# Is it possible to use Glide to download image to load into a TextView?

Tags: android, android-glide

In my app I download an image from an URL and set it into an ImageView through Glide, however, I'm trying to remove a few unnecessary layouts, so is it possible to use Glide to download an image and set into to TextView?

```
try {
  Glide.with(holder.logo.getContext())
       .load(standingObjectItems.get(position).getImgId()).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
       .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
       .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
       .into(holder.logo);

} catch (IllegalArgumentException | IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: How would you set the `Bitmap` on the `ImageView`?

Comment: You mean set The Bitmap on the text view? Well that's my question

Comment: You cannot set an image into a `TextView`. You can set a `Drawable` to the side of the `TextView`, but not inside the `TextView` itself.

Comment: @Emmanuel exactly that's my question..... Do I download the image with glide as a bitmap then convert it as a drawable or is there a smarter way..?

Comment: You can download it as a `Bitmap` and then wrap it around a `BitmapDrawable` and `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds()`

Comment: @tinysunlight Alright

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
Glide.with(left.getContext())
     .load(((FixturesListObject) object).getHomeIcon())
     .asBitmap()
     .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(100,100) {
        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation glideAnimation) {
          left.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, new BitmapDrawable(left.getResources(),resource), null, null);
        }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to achieve the same thing and now I can :)

Comment: Thanks. Very useful for me

Comment: load(((FixturesListObject) object).getHomeIcon()) can you explain me about this line

Comment: SimpleTarget is depricated now

Answer (score 14):

In Glide 4.9.0 SimpleTarget is deprecated. You can use CustomTarget instead.

```
Glide.with(myFragmentOrActivity)
         .load(imageUrl)
         .into(new CustomTarget<Drawable>(100,100) {

        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Drawable resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Drawable> transition)
        {
            left.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, resource, null, null);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder)
        {
            left.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, placeholder, null, null);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 6):

Using [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) 4.7.1:

```
Glide.with(context)
     .load(someUrl)
     /* Because we can*/
     .apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())
     /* If a fallback is not set, null models will cause the error drawable to be displayed. If
      * the error drawable is not set, the placeholder will be displayed.*/
     .apply(RequestOptions.placeholderOf(R.drawable.default_photo))
     .into(new SimpleTarget<Drawable>() {
         @Override
         public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Drawable resource,
                 @Nullable Transition<? super Drawable> transition) {
             /* Set a drawable to the left of textView */
             textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(resource, null, null, null);
         }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple example of how to do using Kotlin.

```
GlideApp.with(context)
            .load("url")
            .placeholder(R.drawable.your_placeholder)
            .error(R.drawable.your_error_image)
            .into(object : CustomTarget<Drawable>(100, 100) {
                override fun onLoadCleared(drawable: Drawable?) {
                    header.companyLogoJob.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drawable,null,null,null)
                }

                override fun onResourceReady(res: Drawable, transition: com.bumptech.glide.request.transition.Transition<in Drawable>?) {
                    header.companyLogoJob.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(res,null,null,null)
                }

            })
```